# How can I abbreviate "Equations" and "Recommendations" in a text?

Tags: academic-writing, grammar

When I want to abbreviate the words "Equations" and "Recommendations" in a text, how can I do this?

**for example**

*Solving the above **eqs.** / **eq's.** is not possible unless by computers.*

*After discussing on the research results, we are going to present our **recomms.** / **recomm's.** .*

**Questions**

1- Which one is correct? **eqs.** or **eq's.** ? **recomms.** or **recomm's.**?
2- Is there a kind of freedom to abbreviate any word when it is needed? (For example when constructing a *PowerPoint* presentation, there may not be enough space to type the whole word in a text box and therefore I prefer to use abbreviations).

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* abbreviating in academic writing.  If doing this in the likes of Powerpoint, your presentation just looks sloppy and unprofessional.

Comment: In the title and the first line of the question, replacing "*a text*" with "*a text box*" would make the question a lot more understandable.

Comment: @RayButterworth a _text box_  of a _powerpoint_ presentation is only an example, my question is general.

Comment: @Alish, I initially interpreted "*in a text*" in the question as meaning "*in a SMS text message*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for any abbreviation or acronym, one should write the full word out the first time, followed by a parenthetical note as to the shortened form you will be doing, then use the shortened form for the remainder.

If it's someone's preferred name, then it would be done between the given name and the surname as it would appear in a legal document.

> When we look at the following equations (eq.) we find that eq. 17 does not conform to the pattern...
>
> The Federal Buera of Investigation (FBI) announced that they had arrested the vice President for murder of a giraffe.
>
> A spokes person for Vice President Geoffrey "Giraffe-Killer" Jones said that the Vice President did nothing wrong and that his actions fell within the preview of his duties.

Answer (score 2):

"Equations" should not be abbreviated unless it is appearing with an equation number, in which case the standard abbreviation styles are "Eq. 3" and "Eqs. 4-6".

I don't think abbreviating "recommendations" would ever be necessary in academic writing.

Answer (score 0):

For ppt use EQ.  and REC. to make them fit.
For formal writing spell them out.

Answer (score 0):

In scientific papers, Eq. is pretty common.